# How to Send Money Dogecoin With NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, cryptojs, cryptocurrency

I'm learning to make a simple Dogecoin wallet terminal for personal use. I managed to generate a private key and public address (using [coinkey](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinkey)). And success check balance Dogecoin (using [API Dogechain](https://dogechain.info/api/simple)).

But, I'm still confused about sending Dogecoin from the private key that I generated. Is there a NodeJS module that can be used to send Dogecoin from a private key? Or maybe anyone has an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a running instance of dogecoind to connect with. If you're running Debian/Ubuntu, this worked for me: http://www.dogeco.in/wiki/index.php/Dogecoind

Then, install the node-dogecoin NPM package. (https://github.com/countable/node-dogecoin)

npm install node-dogecoin

```
var dogecoin = require('node-dogecoin')()

dogecoin
.auth('MyUserName', 'mypassword')
.getNewAddress()
.getBalance()
```

Comment: The first link goes to Binance now.

Comment: The first link now goes to some website that advertises viruses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node - dogecoin](https://github.com/countable/node-dogecoin). is a simple wrapper for dogecoin wallet (and i think that is compatible with all Litecoin-compatible wallet, but not tested yet).
In this way you can generate private key, check balance, send coins and so on within a unique nodejs module